# NatTable Filter using Regex

Tags: nattable

I am interested in using regular expressions in the NatTable filter. I have set up my code based on the following helpful links:

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/NatTable/article.html#exercise-adding-a-filter-functionality-to-a-nattable

https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1069806/

From what I can gather, it basically boils down to adding the following code to your existing Filter:

```
    FilterRowHeaderComposite<T> filterRowHeaderLayer = new
      FilterRowHeaderComposite<>(filterStrategy,
            sortHeaderLayer, columnHeaderDataLayer.
            getDataProvider(), configRegistry);

    int rowNum = 2;

    configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(EditConfigAttributes.CELL_EDITOR,
      new FilterRowTextCellEditor(), DisplayMode.NORMAL, 
      FilterRowDataLayer.FILTER_ROW_COLUMN_LABEL_PREFIX + rowNum);

    configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(FilterRowConfigAttributes.
      TEXT_MATCHING_MODE, TextMatchingMode.REGULAR_EXPRESSION, 
      DisplayMode.NORMAL,           
      FilterRowDataLayer.FILTER_ROW_COLUMN_LABEL_PREFIX + rowNum);

    configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(CellConfigAttributes.
      DISPLAY_CONVERTER, new FilterRowRegularExpressionConverter(), 
      DisplayMode.NORMAL,            
      FilterRowDataLayer.FILTER_ROW_COLUMN_LABEL_PREFIX + rowNum);
```

The filtering seems to work in certain situations and not others.  For example, assume I have a cell that has the data "This is a Test". If I use the expression *t, it will find the row (which is what I expect).  If I use the expression *x, it will not find the row (which is what I expect). If I use the expression ^(123) it will not find the row (which is NOT what I expect).  Am I doing something incorrect?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is in the regular expression. It seems that the cardinality is missing. Using [^123]* it works as you expect it.

If you for example test the _6031_GlazedListsFilterExample and insert [^abc] for the Housenumber column, you will see all entries that have only a one digit value. Adding the * all rows appear.